# Find playlists from x track using Spotify API

Tags: api, rest, spotify

I'm trying to figure out what makes ForTunes tick.

How they can tell me as an artist that my track is being added to x playlist?

I've been looking through all the developer DOCS, but can't seem to find the right REST point to be able to do this.

The closest REST point seems to be this Get Playlist Items.
It mentions the ability to include a track/artist as a query param in fields.
But doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Can someone maybe point me in the right direction?

What REST should I try to use?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring it out. You can't use a track field filter when searching for playlists on /search. No endpoint given a track seems to include playlists. 
I suppose you could constantly search for playlists and scan them, but that seems absurd.

Comment: Yep that seems crazy, there have to be an easier way, but the Spotify docs are only "basic" use cases :)